# slug field on flask

Tags: python, flask, slug

I want to create a slug field stored in database.

I searched and I found http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/5/ but I'm having trouble integrating the code in my app.

This is my `modele.py`:

```
from unicodedata import normalize


def slugfy(text, encoding=None,
        permitted_chars='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-'):
    if isinstance(text, str):
        text = text.decode(encoding or 'ascii')
    clean_text = text.strip().replace(' ', '-').lower()
    while '--' in clean_text:
        clean_text = clean_text.replace('--', '-')
    ascii_text = normalize('NFKD', clean_text).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
    strict_text = map(lambda x: x if x in permitted_chars else '', ascii_text)
    return ''.join(strict_text)


class Chanteur(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    nom = db.Column(db.String(200), index = True, unique = True)
    slug = db.Column(db.String(255))
    chanteurs = db.relationship('Chanson', backref = 'chanteur', lazy = 'dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Chanteur %r>' % (self.nom)

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        super(Chanteur, self).__setattr__(key, value)
        if key == 'nom':
            self.slug = slugfy(self.nom)


class Chanson(db.Model):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
        titre = db.Column(db.String(255))
        chanteur_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('chanteur.id'))

        def __repr__(self):
            return '<Chanson %r>' % (self.titre)
```

It is not working: when I add a new objet (chanteur) the slug field is empty

Answer (score 18):

To persist the slug in the database, I use the following approach (employing the very helpful [`python-slugify`](https://github.com/un33k/python-slugify) library):

```
from slugify import slugify  # among other things

class Song(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(255))
    slug = db.Column(db.String(255))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not 'slug' in kwargs:
            kwargs['slug'] = slugify(kwargs.get('title', ''))
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 8):

A small improvement on [@berislav-lopac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/122033/berislav-lopac) suggestion's, Using [python-slugify](https://github.com/un33k/python-slugify) you can

```
from slugify import slugify


class SlugModel(Base):
    name = Column(String)
    slug = Column(String)

    @staticmethod
    def slugify(target, value, oldvalue, initiator):
        if value and (not target.slug or value != oldvalue):
            target.slug = slugify(value)

event.listen(SlugModel.name, 'set', SlugModel.slugify, retval=False)
```

This will update slug's column content on create\update

if you want even a better solution, you can use the @hybrid_property decorator as suggested [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html)

Answer (score 1):

Install package called [Webhelpers](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/WebHelpers/1.3) and it makes slugification a piece of cake.

```
from webhelpers.text import urlify


class Chanteur(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    nom = db.Column(db.String(200), index=True, unique=True)
    chanteurs = db.relationship('Chanson', backref='chanteur', lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Chanteur %r>' % (self.nom)

    @property
    def slug(self):
        return urlify(self.nom)


class Chanson(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    titre = db.Column(db.String(255))
    chanteur_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('chanteur.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Chanson %r>' % (self.titre)

    @property
    def slug(self):
        return urlify(self.nom)
```

Refer [docs](https://webhelpers.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/text.html#webhelpers.text.urlify) for more info.

Comment: What if the OP wants to *search* for objects by slug?

Comment: thanks but the code that you give me is not stored the slug in database so if i change the title of some chanson it will change the slug too , i think this is bad for SEO

Comment: @MartijnPieters `@classmethod
    def find_by_slug(cls, slug):
        return SomeThing.query.filter(SomeThing.slug == slug).first()`

Comment: @ajkumar25: **but you are not storing the slug**.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think maybe slugs are one way --- if you need search you need another layer of indirection (i.e., pass an ID in your url)

Answer (score 0):

Salute,

you can do this way if you want the slug field represents le titre de la Chanson.

```
from unicodedata import normalize


def slug(text, encoding=None,
         permitted_chars='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-'):
    if isinstance(text, str):
        text = text.decode(encoding or 'ascii')
    clean_text = text.strip().replace(' ', '-').lower()
    while '--' in clean_text:
        clean_text = clean_text.replace('--', '-')
    ascii_text = normalize('NFKD', clean_text).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
    strict_text = map(lambda x: x if x in permitted_chars else '', ascii_text)
    return ''.join(strict_text)



class Chanson(object):

    titre = ''
    slugfield = ''

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        super(Chanson, self).__setattr__(key, value)
        if key == 'titre':
            self.slugfield = slug(self.titre)

m = Chanson()
m.titre = 'Non, je ne regrette rien'
print m.titre
print m.slugfield
```

The slug method was grabbed from [here](https://gist.github.com/turicas/1428479)

*Edited*

```
def slug(text):
    #slugfy logic here


class Chanson(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    titre = db.Column(db.String(255))
    chanteur_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('chanteur.id'))
    slugfield = db.Column(db.String(255))

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        super(Chanson, self).__setattr__(key, value)
        if key == 'titre':
            self.slugfield = slug(self.titre)
```

Comment: Which orm lib are you using?

Comment: Are you importing sqlalchemy as db?

Comment: yes i am importing sqlalchemy and yes i am using Flask-SQLAlchemy

Comment: @anouar your code is working. Could you explain what is not working?

Comment: i have flask-admin to add objet(chanteur) , check this photo http://postimg.org/image/cdj4xxob7/  , i the first test i aded the slug manually like that first-test and when i enter to localhost:5000/first-test it work . in the second test i write the nom of chanteur so the slug will be insered automaticlly right ? but it not working .

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an article about this topic. My approach is to use the 'before_commit' event for the session. You can read about it [here](https://digitalhedgehog.org/articles/how-to-manage-slugs-for-database-entities-with-flask-and-sqlalchemy)

Answer (score -2):

in the slug function above, you need to do the loop

```
clean_text.replace('--', '-')
```

AFTER you reduce it to permitted characters. If you don't: `This & That` will be returned as `this--that`.