# Slug field in SQL Alchemy/FlaskAdmin

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I am trying to create a slug field in one of my DB models.  I am using Flask-SQLAlchemy and Flask-Admin.  My Class is defined as:

```
class Merchant(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'merchants'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String())
    ...
    slug = db.Column(db.String())

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Merchant: {}'.format(self.name)
```

I have attempted to implement something like this from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23657483/slug-field-on-flask):

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not 'slug' in kwargs:
            kwargs['slug'] = slugify(kwargs.get('name', ''))
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

However it does not work when I am creating the new Merchant using Flask-Admin.

In trying to determine why, I change the init function to simply `print kwargs`.  When I create a new Merchant in Flask-Admin, it prints `{}`, however when I do it in the python shell, like `Merchant(name ='test')`, it prints `{'name' : 'test'}`.

Does anyone know how I can access the arguments being passed to my class at init from Flask-Admin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like Flask-Admin is not passing constructor arguments when initialising the new object and your code doesn't have any effect. I haven't checked the source code, but they could be doing something like:

```
m = Merchant()
...
m.name = 'foo'
```

I think your best bet if you want to continue using Flask-Admin would be extending the `ModelView` and implementing the `on_model_change` hook:

```
class MerchantModelView(BaseModelView):

    def on_model_change(self, form, model, is_created):
        if is_created and not model.slug:
            model.slug = slugify(model.name)
```

You can fine more information in [the documentation](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_model/#flask_admin.model.BaseModelView.on_model_change).